# How to start and stop highlights?

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting, spell-checking, jtextpane

I have a seemingly small problem, but I couldn't find a clear answer in the past 2 days. I am creating an auto-completing spell checker which checks a JTextPane (called `mainTxtTypeArea`). I can get the current word the user is working on, with it's beginning and end indices, but when I only want to highlight the one specific word the highlighter will just continue beyond the typed word. This the code called when a document event happens:

```
public void checkWord(DocumentEvent e) {
            try {
                Highlighter redZigZag = mainTxtTypeArea.getHighlighter();
                int start = Utilities.getWordStart(mainTxtTypeArea, e.getOffset());
                int end = Utilities.getWordEnd(mainTxtTypeArea, e.getOffset());
                int length = end - start;
                String word = mainTxtTypeArea.getDocument().getText(start, length);

                if(dictionary.find(word) == false && Character.isWhitespace(word.charAt(0)) == false){
                    System.out.println("Incorrect: "+word);
                    //I found a zigzag highlighter online, but the default yields the same result
                    redZigZag.addHighlight(start, end, painter);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Correct: "+word);
                }

            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {}
        }
```

I am open to any alternatives as well. I tried using Styles, but it throws an exception, because styles can't be applied in a document listener.

Comment: I would suggest using an existing component over trying to implement syntax highlighting on your own. You should try [RSyntaxTextArea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/) which is a JTextArea with such functionality built in. It's open-source and very extensible. Even has an auto-completion framework.

Comment: @predi Thanks for the post, but I am not allowed to use any external programs or data structures. That's the aim of the project. I'll have a look at the source code though.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have found an alternative. Instead of using a document listener I use a KeyReleased action event to monitor my text pane and then just make the misspelt word red italics. The code is below:

```
private void mainTxtTypeAreaKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    checkWord();
}

private void checkWord() {
    try {
        int start = Utilities.getWordStart(mainTxtTypeArea, mainTxtTypeArea.getCaretPosition());
        int end = Utilities.getWordEnd(mainTxtTypeArea, mainTxtTypeArea.getCaretPosition());
        int length = end - start;

        if(length > 0) {
            StyledDocument doc = mainTxtTypeArea.getStyledDocument();
            SimpleAttributeSet as = new SimpleAttributeSet();

            if(dictionary.find(doc.getText(start, length)) == false){
                StyleConstants.setItalic(as, true);
                StyleConstants.setForeground(as, Color.red);
            } else {
                StyleConstants.setItalic(as, false);
                StyleConstants.setForeground(as, Color.BLACK);
            }
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(start, length, as, false);
        }
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```